# How to create a list of youtube components on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm try to build a loop to create with each iteration a YouTube Component with a configuration parameter of type object, this object has a property with the Id video YouTube

This is a S.O. Windows 10, grunt, react.js, less

```
const YouTubeComponent = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount() { this.youtubeController(this.props.generalConfig.youtubeId) },
    youtubeController(youtubeId) {
        window.player = {};
        player = { playVideo: (container, videoId) => { player.loadPlayer(container, videoId); },
            loadPlayer: (container, videoId) => {
                new YT.Player(container, {
                    videoId: videoId,                    
                    playerVars: {
                        'modestbranding': 1,
                        'controls': 1,
                        'autoplay': 0,
                        'enablejsapi': 1,
                        'frameborder': 0,
                        'loop': 1,
                        'rel': 0,
                        'playlist': videoId,
                    },
                    events: { 'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange }
                });
            }
        };
        player.playVideo(youtubeId, youtubeId);
    },
    render() {...},
});
```

I expect differents objects (window.player) of each component rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it differently:

- create wrapper component which will receive an array of video players object
- the wrapper component should map the array and for each object render a Player component which will render eah video player object.

Something like (pseudo code)

```
export default PlayerWrapper(players) => {
  return(
    players.map(player => {
      return <VideoPlayer setting={player.options}/>
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must a have a container component, and in a loop you can display your child component.

A sample example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import YouTubeComponent from "./YouTubeComponent";

export default class Container extends Component {
  state = {
    videos: [{}, {}]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.videos.map(video => (
          <YouTubeComponent key={video.id} generalConfig={video} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```